# An equation for an extremely convex (curved) function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis, curves

Suppose we have four points, $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$

Is anyone able to provide me with an equation for a function that is

- nearly flat  $x_1,x_2$ (i.e. $f(x_1)/f(x_2) \approx 1)$
- Steep between $x_3,x_4$ (specifically, I want $\frac{f(x_3)}{f(x_4)}<\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_2)}$)
- strictly increasing, continuous, positive, and convex over the positive reals

For example, suppose $x_1 = 2.2,x_2=5,x_3=7.5,x_4=9$,
Is there a convex, strictly increasing, function where  $\frac{f(x_3)}{f(x_4)}<\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_2)}$

---

Some comments:

- Im okay with either a general answer or an answer for the specific points i have given
- convexity is not a requirement as long as the function is strictly increasing (**I prefer if it is convex though**

  - I'd like $f(0)=0$ if possible (but not required)

I've been generating a bunch of points in mathematica and trying to generate a curve, but i haven't had luck.

I have also tried an exponential function (this is the steepest thing I could think of),but then $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ need to satisfy $x_1+x_4 > x_3+x_2$, (which my example points don't satisfy)

This has been bugging me because its so easy to draw such a function, but I haven't been able to come up with an equation.

Comment: Steepness would usually be reflected by comparing $\frac {f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$ with its counterpart not just comparing ratios of function values.

Comment: @RossMillikan My terminology here is poor, sorry. I was basically reference tot the fact that $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_2)}{x_2-x_1)}$ would be large at a specific part of the function (and thereafter)

Comment: But the question talks about ratios of function values at different points, not an expression like this, which approximates the slope over the interval.

Comment: If you want extremely steep functions you can try $e^{e^x}$, $e^{e^{e^x}}$ and so on.

Comment: @Rahul Man... I was trying variation on $e^x$, like $\frac{e^x}{.9e^x+C}$ to try and make the derivative really small until $e^x$ got huge, but it wasn't working. Your suggesting though works and is simply. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g(x)$ is strictly increasing and convex then $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ is strictly increasing, positive, and convex. Then the requirement $f(x_4)/f(x_3)>f(x_2)/f(x_1)$ reduces to $g(x_4)-g(x_3)>g(x_2)-g(x_1)$. It is much easier to construct such a function, for example by setting $g(x)=1/(c-x)$ when $x_1\le x\le x_4$ and extending linearly outside this interval.

Comment: By extending linearly you mean $g(x) = 1/(c-x_4) + \frac{d}{dx}(1/(c-x))\vert_{x=x_4} x$ for $x>x_4$ (and similar for $x<x_1$)?. If I'm interpreting that correctly, the change in second derivative at these points won't prevent the function from being differentiable, right? (i.e. it won't make a kink, because we are extending linearly?).

Comment: Yes, except the second term will be $\frac{d}{dx}(\cdots)|_{x=x_4}(x-x_4)$. The function will be continuous and differentiable but not twice differentiable. (You don't have to extend linearly if you don't want to, but then you will have to restrict the domain of the function to $x<c$.)

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is to define $x_c=\frac 12{x_2+x_3}$, then 
$$f(x)=e^{k(x-x_c)}$$
The side below $x_c$ will be pretty flat because it is like $e^x$ for $x \lt 0$ while the side above is like $x \gt 0$.  Increase $k$ to make it more pronounced.

Comment: But does this give $\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_2)}\approx 1$ (like .9 or something?). A quick look seems like it doesn't. (However, maybe if I define $x_c=x_3$? Ill take a look

Comment: You can make $k$ vary with $x$ and be quite small below $x_c$ to make that true.

Comment: That works! Except I think it makes the function become decreasing near $0$? (because if $k$k depends on $x$ we have something like $e^{x^2-x_c*x}$. Im Likely making $k$ depend on $x$ incorrectly though.

Comment: No, as long as $k$ stays positive the function will always be increasing.

Comment: If $k$ varies with $x$ (say by simply making $k=x$) then the derivative is negative for very small $x$. (because then $-x_c * k$ is larger than $x$ at small $x$

Comment: $(e^{kx})'=e^{kx}k$ so as long as $k \gt 0$ the function will be increasing

Comment: Apologies, I thought there was a product rule so that it was $(e^{kg(x)})'=e^{kg(x)}(kg'(x)+k'g(x))$, where here $g(x)=(x-x_c)$. And then even if $k'$ is not negative, $k'g(x)$ can be. (in this case when $x<x_c$

Comment: Yes, you need to keep $k'$ positive as well

Comment: Do you mean $\frac12(x_2+x_3)$ instead of $\frac12x_2+x_3$?

Comment: Yes, I got braces instead of parentheses